# Need to remove pages full link path from the web link

Tags: .htaccess

I need to remove pages full link path from the web link: `http://web.example.com/web/#bwc/index.php` to be `http://web.example.com/`

What modifications has to be done?

Comment: I did not tried any thing I am using SugarCRM where code already there in .htaccess. Do you want to see that code? How can I send that code here? The code is consists of 57 lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule test_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope it will help..

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apache, https://gist.github.com/wataruoguchi/649963c3ee18640e0105 will be the answer.

```
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/maintenance.html
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=503,L]
</IfModule>
```

You can simply rewrite `maintain.html` to `index.html`